# How to suspend DataTables from automaticallay reloading ajax data

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables

I'm having a DataTable that loads its data via ajax from the server.
It works pretty fine so far.

I add a row using `usersTable.row.add( ["0", "0", "0", "0"] ).draw();` it will be displayed shortly but immediately overwritten by ajax.

Is there a possibility to disable ajax temporarily?

Comment: The better way would be to add the new row via ajax to your db and then reload the data. This way you can be sure that data is really stored.

Comment: That is what I'm currently doing, but I thought it is ridiculous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass false to the reset option in the draw function like so:

```
usersTable.row.add( ["0", "0", "0", "0"] ).draw(false);
```

This will maintain the current paging position and thus will not trigger the AJAX call.

[Datatables 1.10 API - draw()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/draw%28%29)

Comment: sorry, this doesn't work for me. Here is the modified code
`var usersTable = $("#usersTable").DataTable( {
  ajax: "<?php echo URL ?>json/get-users-json.php?",

      columns: [
    { "title": "ID" },              
          { "title": "Nick" },
          { "title": "Forename" },
          { "title": "Lastname" }
      ]
  } );  
  
  $('#addUser').on( 'click', function () {
   usersTable.row.add( [ "0", "0", "0", "0" ] ).draw(false);
  } );`

Comment: Immediately after displaying the new row the whole table will be refreshed and thus the new added row is gone.

Comment: For the array-based format of your data, you can specify the columnDefs option instead of columns. Your columnDefs might look like this:

`columnDefs: [
{ targets: 0, title: "ID"},
{ targets: 1, title: "Nick"},
{ targets: 2, title: "Forename"},
{ targets: 3, title: "Lastname"}
]`

An example: [http://jsfiddle.net/wE3kP/](http://jsfiddle.net/wE3kP/)

Comment: Thanks you mathewbergt. I understand your hint only as option for writing code nicely, right?
It will not affect the reload issue, isn't it?

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear. Your problem is that you are not initializing the 'columns' option correctly. You can actually use 'columns' OR 'columnDefs', but you MUST specify the 'targets' option if you are using 2D arrays, otherwise Datatables doesn't know how to map the JSON data to the internal data object. So, here is another example of how you can initialize your Datatable, this time using the 'columns' option and specify the target for each column:
`columns: [ { targets: 0, title: "ID"}, { targets: 1, title: "Nick"}, { targets: 2, title: "Forename"}, { targets: 3, title: "Lastname"} ]`

Comment: If you look at the XHR requests in the example Fiddle I provided, you will notice that clicking on the 'Add Users' button does NOT generate additional AJAX calls.

Comment: Thank you all for looking into this issue. The reason why the datatables gets refreshed was, that I have had the *add user* button inside a html-form. that cause to refresh the page.